# Is the number non-zero elements of a reduced row echelon form matrix unique up to column permutations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a given $m \times n$ matrix $A$, I am told that it's reduced row echelon form $\textrm{rref}(A)$ is unique up to row permutations of $A$, but non-unique up to column permutations of $A$.

My question is: given two matrices $A$ and $A^\prime$, which are equal up to column permutations,  is the number of non-zero elements of $\textrm{rref}(A)$ equal to $\textrm{rref}(A^\prime)$?

More generally, what properties of $\textrm{rref}(A)$ are also shared by any $\textrm{rref}(A^\prime)$?

Comment: What does "unique up to row permutations" mean? If you take the rref of A and permute its rows nontrivially, it will no longer be in rref.

Comment: By this I mean, if you take A and permute it's rows to produce A*, then rref(A*) = rref(A). Perhaps this is not true, although I have been told it was, and it seems likely given that finding an RREF requires row permutations anyway.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second part of the question: No, the RREF of $A$ and the RREF obtained from $A$ by permuting its columns do not have to have the same number of nonzero elements. The RREF of $\pmatrix{-1&-1&1&0\cr 1&1&1&-2\cr}$ has five nonzero elements, but the RREF of $\pmatrix{0&1&-1&-1\cr -2&1&1&1\cr}$ has six. (There don't appear to be any $2\times3$ counterexamples, though.)